# Generating dart json_seriaziable file wont work

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a Dart class that I want to automatically serialize to and from json. However, I can't generate the part file for it.

```
root@430f48d3ead0:/workspaces/zstore/src# pub run build_runner build
[INFO] Generating build script completed, took 464ms
[INFO] Reading cached asset graph completed, took 123ms
[INFO] Checking for updates since last build completed, took 666ms
[INFO] Running build completed, took 19ms
[INFO] Caching finalized dependency graph completed, took 174ms
[INFO] Succeeded after 241ms with 0 outputs (0 actions)
```

Here's my file **order.dart**

```
import 'package:json_annotation/json_annotation.dart';
import 'product.dart';

part 'order.g.dart';

@JsonSerializable()
class Order {
  String _id;
  bool deleted;
  String clientName;
  String clientPhone;
  DateTime date;
  int orderNumber;
  String observations;
  List<Product> products;
  double total;
  factory Order.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => _$OrderFromJson(json);
  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => _$OrderToJson(this);
}
```

I got no errors in the output of the command as you can see, but I also get no `order.g.dart` file

**pubspec.yaml:**

```
name: zstore
description: Simple store api

environment:
  sdk: '>=2.1.0 <3.0.0'

dependencies:
  json_annotation: ^3.0.1

dev_dependencies:
  build_runner: ^1.7.4
  json_serializable: ^3.2.5
  test: ^1.0.0
```

Comment: What does your pubspec file look like?

Comment: @Abion47 updated please take a look

Comment: why not just write your own serialization for the class? Then i presume you dont need the annotation or *_$OrderToJson()* etc

Comment: @Fallenreaper because I'm gonna work with lots of classes

Comment: The working directory on that command appears to be `/workspaces/zstore/src`. Is this the root folder of your Flutter project?

Comment: @Abion47 it is not a Flutter project. Above src there is nothing. And pubspec is in `src`

Comment: (As a tangent, the recently released [freezed](https://pub.dev/packages/freezed) package adds sealed data classes to Dart, and it has been designed with json_serializable compatibility in mind. Have you considered going that route rather than using json_serializable directly?)

Comment: You tagged your question with `flutter`, so I assumed it was a Flutter project. Regardless, I've never tried using build_runner in a non-Flutter project, but I would guess that it's still going to look in a `lib` directory for your classes by default (as that is the Dart idiom). Is your *order.dart* file in there?

Comment: @Abion47 the model was in /models but I placed it in the src folder and it still didn't work

Comment: Not the `src` folder. The `lib` folder. You can put it in `lib/src/models` if you like, as long as all your code exists somewhere in a `lib` folder.

Comment: @Abion47 where does `pubspeck.yam` goes? I've left  it in `lib`, did pub get, it did some things, but didn't generate anything in `lib/src/models/`

Comment: The typical Dart project structure is `<root>/pubspec.yaml` and `<root>/lib/<code files>`.